Infinite images and translate 3D use HTML, SSC, JS and Bootrstrap
Can you help me to do infinite images and translate 3d like this link [https://public.work/]
I'm use html,css, js, and bootstrap 5
Your response is very helpful to me, if there is alternative other than that code, just tell me what should i do:)
I'm expect the result like this link [https://public.work/]
my code
html:
<main>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4 col-xl-3">
        <a href="pages/rib/products/blackShirt.html"
          ><img
            src="assets/images/rib/BLACK-SHIRT.jpg"
            class="img-fluid"
            alt="black-shirt"
        /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 col-xl-3">
        <a href="pages/rib/products/whiteShirt.html"
          ><img
            src="assets/images/rib/WHITE-SHIRT.JPG"
            class="img-fluid"
            alt="white-shirt"
        /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 col-xl-3">
        <a href="pages/rib/products/greyShirt.html"
          ><img
            src="assets/images/rib/GREY-SHIRT.JPG"
            class="img-fluid"
            alt="grey-shirt"
        /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 col-xl-3">
        <a href="pages/rib/products/blackCap.html"
          ><img
            src="assets/images/rib/BLACK-CAP.jpg"
            class="img-fluid"
            alt="black-cap"
        /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 col-xl-3">
        <a href="pages/rib/products/redCap.html"
          ><img
            src="assets/images/rib/RED-CAP.jpg"
            class="img-fluid"
            alt="red-cap"
        /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 col-xl-3">
        <a href="pages/podium-ocra/products/teamJersey.html"
          ><img
            src="assets/images/podium-ocra/team-jersey.jpg"
            class="img-fluid"
            alt="team-jersey"
        /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 col-xl-3">
        <a href="pages/podium-ocra/products/ocraGreen.html">
          <img
            src="assets/images/podium-ocra/ocra-green.jpg"
            class="img-fluid"
            alt="shirt-black"
          />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 col-xl-3">
        <a href="pages/podium-ocra/products/toteBag.html">
          <img
            src="assets/images/podium-ocra/tote-bag.jpg"
            class="img-fluid"
            alt="shirt-black"
          />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 col-xl-3">
        <a href="pages/podium-ocra/products/glassCup.html">
          <img
            src="assets/images/podium-ocra/glass-cup.jpg"
            class="img-fluid"
            alt="shirt-black"
          />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 col-xl-3">
        <a href="pages/podium-ocra/products/stickerPack.html">
          <img
            src="assets/images/podium-ocra/sticker-pack.jpg"
            class="img-fluid"
            alt="shirt-black"
          />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 col-xl-3">
        <a href="pages/podium-ocra/products/capNavy.html">
          <img
            src="assets/images/podium-ocra/cap-navy.jpg"
            class="img-fluid"
            alt="shirt-black"
          />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 col-xl-3">
        <a href="pages/podium-ocra/products/capBlue.html">
          <img
            src="assets/images/podium-ocra/cap-blue.jpg"
            class="img-fluid"
            alt="shirt-black"
          />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 col-xl-3">
        <a href="pages/podium-ocra/products/capGreen.html">
          <img
            src="assets/images/podium-ocra/cap-green.jpg"
            class="img-fluid"
            alt="shirt-black"
          />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>

css:
  main {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container-fluid {
  width: 150%;
  height: 100%;
}

.img-fluid:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media (max-width: 576px) {
  .container-fluid {
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
  }
}

js:
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  const images = document.querySelectorAll("main .img-fluid");

  images.forEach((img) => {
    img.style.cursor = "pointer";
    img.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
      img.style.cursor = "grabbing";
      const shiftX = e.clientX - img.getBoundingClientRect().left;
      const shiftY = e.clientY - img.getBoundingClientRect().top;

      const moveAt = (pageX, pageY) => {
        img.style.left = pageX - shiftX + "px";
        img.style.top = pageY - shiftY + "px";
      };

      const onMouseMove = (e) => {
        moveAt(e.pageX, e.pageY);
      };

      document.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);

      img.onmouseup = () => {
        document.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
        img.style.cursor = "grab";
        img.onmouseup = null;
      };
    });

    img.ondragstart = () => {
      return false;
    };
  });
});


This setup will create an infinite scroll effect where placeholder images are loaded dynamically as the user scrolls down the page. Adjust the limit variable if you want to load more or fewer images per scroll. I hope you are familiar with promises and timeouts.


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const imageContainer = document.getElementById("image-container");
  const loading = document.getElementById("loading");

  let page = 1;
  const limit = 10; // Number of images to load per request

  const fetchImages = () => {
    // Simulate an API request to fetch images
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const images = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
          images.push(
            `https://via.placeholder.com/600x200?text=Image+${
              (page - 1) * limit + i + 1
            }`
          );
        }
        resolve(images);
      }, 1000); // Simulate network delay
    });
  };

  const loadImages = async() => {
    loading.style.display = "block";
    const images = await fetchImages();
    loading.style.display = "none";

    images.forEach((src) => {
      const img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = src;
      img.alt = "Placeholder Image";
      img.classList.add("image");
      imageContainer.appendChild(img);
    });

    page++;
  };

  const handleScroll = () => {
    const scrollTop = window.scrollY;
    const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    const documentHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;

    if (scrollTop + windowHeight >= documentHeight - 10) {
      loadImages();
    }
  };

  // Initial load
  loadImages();

  // Attach scroll event listener
  window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
});
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: lightgrey;
}

.loading {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
<div class="container" id="image-container">
  <!-- Images will be appended here -->
</div>
<div class="loading" id="loading">Loading...</div>




Here is the working example https://codepen.io/tonkec/pen/mdZGPpo

If you are not familiar with promises please read this https://javascript.info/promise-basics
